# Why wget downloads some zip files as html?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download some files from this link with `wget`:

```
wget http://geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/PaginasPublicas/downloadIfr.aspx?orig=DownloadQuadriculas&arq=3241-1&amp;arqTipo=MDT
```

However, what I get here is a very short HTML file instead. If I open this link in a browser this is an ok link and I can download the file. Is there any specific parameter I should use with `wget` to manage to download files from some websites? Or is that a problem specific from this website that's blocking automated downloads somehow?

Comment: read the content of the html file

Comment: The HTML is what you download, that then loads the zip file. If you expand the wget commands to download more it may get the zip file, or the html may block automated downloads, there's a lot of ways to do it, what you can know is they don't want auto downloads of their content.

Comment: @Lizardx Yeah... It's a page of open data but I think they've designed it for not having automatic downloads. If I try to open the downloaded HTML with my browser I won't download the zip file though... It seems there's some specific logic behind it just so it only works when I come from the original link using the browser.

Comment: read the html, like the first commenter said. Many times it will be a file not found page, or something like that, because the actual download was run through javascript or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page loads an iFrame using a modified URL:

- Add prefix `download.` to the URL
- Replace `downloadIfr.aspx` with `downloadArquivo.aspx`
- Fix the encoding and replace `&amp;` with `&`

```
wget -O 3241-1.zip "http://download.geosampa.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/PaginasPublicas/downloadArquivo.aspx?orig=DownloadQuadriculas&arq=3241-1&arqTipo=MDT"
```